# Why can't I remove an attribute of all children?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a cloned div containing input elements, all of which are disabled. I am trying to use the following JQuery code to remove the disabled attribute of each of the div's children.

```
clonedElement.children().removeAttr('disabled');
```

I do not have a ton of JQuery experience, so I am probably misunderstanding the way this is supposed to work. How should I be going about removing the "disabled" attribute from all children of the cloned node?

If it helps, clonedElement was created with the JQuery .clone() method.

HTML I AM USING TO TEST---

```
        <div id="original_item" class="hidden">
            <div class="row_submit">
                <div class="med_field">
                    <p>Product:</p>
                    <select name="product[]">
                        <option></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="small_field">
                    <p>Type:</p>
                    <select name="type[]">
                        <option></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="small_field">
                    <p>Price:</p>
                    <input type="text" name="price[]" value="test" disabled="disabled" />
                </div>
                <div class="small_field">
                    <p>Quantity:</p>
                    <input type="text" name="quantity[]" />
                </div>
                <img onclick="removeItem(this);" title="Remove Item" style="margin: 18px 0 0 12px;" src="icons/cancel.gif" />
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="warehouse_data[]" />
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you show the HTML?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`children` only looks in **immediate children** and if the clonedElement is not one of med_field/small-field then it would not work.

You can use `find()` instead to search for elements beyond immediate children.

i.e.

```
//for jQuery < 1.6
$("*", clonedElement).removeAttr("disabled");
//or
clonedElement.find("*").removeAttr("disabled");

//for jQuery >= 1.6
$("*", clonedElement).removeProp("disabled");
//or
clonedElement.find("*").removeProp("disabled");
```

Comment: Perfect. The children thing definitely makes sense now that I think about it. Thank you.

Comment: Rather than using the "*" selector, I would just select the elements that you need: `clonedElement.find('input,select')`. While it doesn't make a difference in this situation, it's more efficient, and it's good practice to avoid doing things you didn't intend to do.

Comment: @Jamietre: If OP is using this for removing just the disabled attribute, then yes...we can simple use input/select selectors

Comment: Disabled only applies to form controls, so that was my assumption :) http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1

Comment: @Jamietre: Yes, disabled applies to the input elements and that's why I agreed with you (if the user was indeed only looking for disabled attribute)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery <1.6 your current code should work.

jQuery 1.6+ do this: `clonedElement.children().removeProp('disabled');`

See this question [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) for reasons why

Comment: `.prop` and `.attr` are both "write to many, read from first only"

Answer (score 0):

as long as clonedElement is a jquery element you can do:

```
clonedElement.children().each(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
});
```